# Excel 2010 VBA lookup function problems

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Function ProtectiveDiscount(PDD As Range)
'‘Find discount in table
TotalDiscount = 0
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

If ListBox1.Selected(i).Value = "Dead bolt, Local Fire Alarm, Fire extinguisher" Then
Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("PDD"), 2, False)
' TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount +  WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Range("R50:S55"), 2, False)
End If

If ListBox1.Selected(i).Value = "Burglar Alarm with Reporting" Then
Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, PDD, 2, False)
' TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Range("R50:S55"), 2, False)
End If

If ListBox1.Selected(i).Value = "Fire Alarm with Reporting" Then
Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("PDD"), 2, False)
 'TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Range("R50:S55"), 2, False)
End If

If ListBox1.Selected(i).Value = "Automatic Sprinkler in all areas" Then
Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("PDD"), 2, False)
' TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, Range("R50:S55"), 2, False)
End If
End Function
```

For some reason my vlookup function does not work. I tried several ways and I am getting stuck. Can anyone provide any help

Comment: I see a `for`, but not a `next`? Is that a typo, or were you actually facing some error?

Comment: There was a next I just could not fit all the code. I dont get an error but I get #Value returned in the cell

Comment: You're not returning any value from your function. Somewhere there should be a line `ProtectiveDiscount = [whateverValueYouCalculated]`  Is there a reason why your second lookup uses the function's PDD parameter and the others do not?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you remove redundancies in your code. Use a `Select Case` statement to check if the current selected value matches one of them, and after the `Select Case` block pass the value into the `VLookup` worksheet function. This may not answer your question, but it may help you focus better on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see the point in using an if ... end if  x4 and not use If ...elseif ... elseif ... end if. But even this may not be needed since actions within Ifs are the same... maybe you should consider an if (a=a1) or (a=a2) or ... Then ... elseif ... else ... end if  form. Anyway, since you may be posting just part of your code I don't say anything further on this. Regarding the Vlookup part, I believe that this form:

```
If ListBox1.Selected(i).Value="Dead bolt, Local Fire Alarm, Fire extinguisher" Then
    Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
    TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(i).Value, PDD, 2, False) 
elseif ListBox1.Selected(i).Value = "Burglar Alarm with Reporting" Then
```

should work fine.

Also a small comment. Although using a worksheet function is easier/faster to write, a search from within VBA using Cells() and looking within the specified range with a for-next loop might be faster, especially since you don't use the Fast Vlookup (with sorted array).

Cheers

Comment: Iterating through cells is rarely faster than a built in function.